# Looking for a faster way of searching for a property in a List of classes

Tags: c#

Below is the class I'm using to represent a tree structure, for displaying files and folders of a game's archive format.

```
public class DirNode : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public String Name { get; set; }
     public int Index { get; private set; }
     public int FileIndex { get; private set; }
     public int Type { get; private set; }
     public List<DirNode> Directories { get; set; }
     public List<FileNode> Files { get; set; }

     public DirNode(String n, int index, int type, int fi)
     {
           Name = n;
           Directories = new List<DirNode>();
           Files = new List<FileNode>();
           Index = index;
           Type = type;
           FileIndex = fi;
     }
}
```

Below is a method of the class that I'm currently using to parse path strings into the tree. It worked well enough when I was only loading one archive, but when trying to "mount" multiple archives, the inefficiency certainly shows

```
 public void AddPath(String[] path, int index, int fileIndex)
        {
            if (path.Length > 1) //It's a Folder;
            {
                bool found = false;
                int i = 0;
                while (i < this.Directories.Count && found == false)//search to see if this folder already exists
                {
                    if (this.Directories[i].Name == path[0])
                    {
                        found = true;
                        String[] newPath = new String[path.Length - 1];
                        Array.Copy(path, 1, newPath, 0, newPath.Length);
                        this.Directories[i].AddPath(newPath, index,fileIndex);
                        return;
                    }

                    i++;
                }
                if (found == false) //new item
                {
                    DirNode dn = new DirNode(path[0], -1, 0,fileIndex);
                    this.Directories.Add(dn);
                    String[] newPath = new String[path.Length - 1];
                    Array.Copy(path, 1, newPath, 0, newPath.Length);
                    this.Directories[this.Directories.Count - 1].AddPath(newPath, index,fileIndex);
                }
            }
            else if (path.Length == 1) //a file!
            {
                DirNode fn = new DirNode(path[0], index, 1,fileIndex);
                this.Directories.Add(fn);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                //really no reason why we should be here. 
                return;
            }
        }
```

I know BinarySearch requires a pre-sorted list, which won't work, as the lists aren't sorted until after the tree is assembled. But it is, ultimately sorted, so a Hash won't work either. If anybody has any ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Of course, if anybody knows of a virtual implementation of the .NET DirectoryInfo class, that would likely even be better.

Comment: Why don't you store the items in Directories and Files sorted at insertion time, so that you can actually perform a binary search on each directory level? The BinarySearch on the List class will give you the index if found and the index complement (use the `~` operator) when not found, so that you know the index where the new item needs to be inserted right away.

Comment: I was under the impression that sorting every time an object is added to the list, would be a serious performance hit, compared to doing it once at the end. Am I wrong?

Comment: Somewhat. But the good thing is: you do **not** need to sort every time, if you pay attention to always insert the new item at the right position so that the list is (and stays) sorted at all times. And as I wrote, finding the insert position comes for free when you do the binary search for finding the existing item! This will drastically improve performance.

Comment: And to elaborate on the performance hit: currently you search for the item, which takes linear time on each insert, so for n inserts you have roughly O(n^2) to perform (worst case). Sorting an already sorted list is no more expensive than this, so yes, your impression is wrong when doing it as you have been doing it. However, my proposal will find the item or the insert position in O(log2(n)), so that the overall performance will be O(n*log2(n)), which is much cheaper overall in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you store the items in Directories and Files sorted at insertion time, so that you can actually perform a binary search on each directory level? The [`BinarySearch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6(v=vs.110).aspx) on the List class will give you the index if found and the index complement (use the `~` operator) when not found, so that you know the index where the new item needs to be inserted right away.

Something like this (not tested in any way, just hacked down in the editor):

Class for comparing the name of two `DirNodes`:

```
internal class DirNodeNameComparer: IComparer<DirNode> {
    public static readonly DirNodeNameComparer Default = new DirNodeNameComparer();

    public int Compare(DirNode x, DirNode y) {
        return string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
    }
}
```

Your AddPath method updated to keep a sorted representation:

```
public void AddPath(String[] path, int index, int fileIndex)
{
    if (path.Length > 1) //It's a Folder;
    {
        DirNode dn = new DirNode(path[0], -1, 0, fileIndex);
        int i = this.Directories.BinarySearch(dn, DirNodeNameComparer.Default);
        if (i < 0) {
            i = ~i;
            this.Directories.Insert(i, dn);
        }
        String[] newPath = new String[path.Length - 1];
        Array.Copy(path, 1, newPath, 0, newPath.Length);
        this.Directories[i].AddPath(newPath, index,fileIndex);
        return;
    }
    else if (path.Length == 1) //a file!
    {
        DirNode fn = new DirNode(path[0], index, 1, fileIndex);
        int i = this.Directories.BinarySearch(fn, DirNodeNameComparer.Default);
        this.Directories.Insert(~i, fn); // really Directories?
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //really no reason why we should be here. 
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, wow. So if a match is found, it returns the index, but if it doesn't, doing a binary NOT on the return, gives you the index of the sorted position in the List - and inserting something at that index, pushes everything down by one to make room for it. That's brilliant - thank you very much! 

Oh, and - yeah I eventually discovered everything could be done simpler with just the one list, using a "type" parameter, Just never got around to deleting "Files", or giving "Directories" a more accurate name. lol

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and happy coding! :)